# How to group set of positive integers so sum of each group is at least S, while maximizing number of groups

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Let's start with a set of positive integers $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n\}$. My goal is to split it into $N$ subsets, such that:

1. the sum of each subset is at least $S$, and
2. $N$ is maximized.

How could I do this?

(Perhaps it is somehow related to the [subset-sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55149/split-a-set-of-numbers-into-2-sets-where-the-sum-of-each-set-is-as-close-to-one) problem?)

**Added Nov 2, 2015**

*Context:*

(I am not sure the context is relevant here but since the moderators ask for it.)

In a statistical problem I am trying to tackle, the total sample size $M$ is too big to be handled in one go. Fortunately, there exists natural grouping of the $M$ data points into $n$ smaller groups, each with size ${x_1,x_2,...,x_n},\sum_i x_i=M$ But then some groups have too few points to make the analysis statistically stable, so I want to form larger groups by combining these small groups, hence the question above.

The closest thing that come up in my search is the [subset-sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55149/split-a-set-of-numbers-into-2-sets-where-the-sum-of-each-set-is-as-close-to-one) problem.

Program-wise, of course I can do a brute-force search (keep combining and check if all groups are at least size $S$), but then I might not reach the optimal grouping (which maximizes $N$). I imagine some sort of integer-programming would yield the result but I wonder if there is a straight-forward algorithm.

Comment: Yes, this seems much like a subset-sum or knapsack problem, the difference being you have a lower bound on the size of pooled data sets rather than an upper bound (capacity).  Therefore the theoretical complexity of such problems is likely NP-hard, but practical methods for approximating the maximum $N$ are perhaps known.  For discussion of related statistical aspects, CrossValidated.SE is worth a look, for example [this Question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12404/what-exactly-does-it-mean-to-pool-data).

Comment: Perhaps you have a "real-world" list of $x_i's$ and threshold $S$ that you'd like to give as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be formulated as a 0-1 (binary) integer programming problem, though that does not mean it necessarily has an efficient solution.  It is known in the literature as the bin covering problem, e.g. [Two simple algorithms for bin covering (1999)](http://www.menet.umn.edu/~zhangs/Reports/1999_CFLZ.pdf), in contrast to the more commonly studied bin packing problem.

The first thing to note is that, with the objective of maximizing $N$ the number of parts in your partition of the data sets $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, any data sets for which $x_i \ge S$ should be assigned to separate parts by themselves.  Thus without loss of generality, all $x_i \lt S$ and $S \gt M = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

An obvious upper bound on the feasible $N$ is $U = \lfloor M/S \rfloor$.  Therefore determining the maximum feasible $N$ is not more difficult than $\log_2 U$ times the complexity of a decision problem for particular $N \le U$.

The special case $N=2$ with $S = M/2$ is called [the partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), and a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm based on dynamic programming is known.  Perhaps surprisingly the case $N=3$ and $S = M/3$ [seems to be more difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Variants_and_generalizations), with [no pseudo-polynomial algorithm unless P=NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem).

The paper by Csirik et al linked in the first paragraph gives algorithms that construct bin coverings in linear or near-linear time in $n$, with proven performance ratios.  That is, depending on the algorithm, achieving half, two-thirds, or three-quarters of the maximum $N$ "bins" covered.  These constructions can be viewed both as lower bounds (achieved) and upper bounds (by the respective performance ratios).

Further developments by Csirik et al are found in [Better Approximation Algorithms for Bin Covering (2000)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.36.5536&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  The approach there is polished by Jansen and Solis-Oba (2003) in [An asymptotic fully polynomial time
approximation scheme for bin covering](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397503003633).

Comment: 'bin-covering' it is. The linked paper (i have only read the 1999 one) is helpful. thanks.